# Alembert method $xy''-y'=x^2e^x$, $y_1=x^2$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks to use the Alembert method to solve $xy''-y'=x^2e^x$, being $y_1=x^2$ a solution of the associated homogeneous equation.

I did $y=ux^2$,

$y'=u'x^2+2xu$,

$y''=u''x^2+4xu'+2u$

$u''x+3u'=e^x$

Making $u'=v$

$v'x+3v=e^x$

then i got $v=(e^x+c_1)/x$

How can i get $u$? Is all i have done before right?

Thanks

Comment: if seems that you have integrated for $v$ incorrectly, according to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27x+%2B+3y+%3D+e%5Ex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $v$ (According to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20xy%27%27%20-y%27%20%3D%20x%5E2e%5Ex)):

$$v = \frac{e^x}{x} - \frac{2e^x}{x^2} + \frac{2e^x}{x^3}$$

When using the reduction of order method (Also known as the method you described above), then you do not need the constant values.

Since $u' = v$

$$u' = \frac{e^x}{x} - \frac{2e^x}{x^2} + \frac{2e^x}{x^3}$$

Integrating we get:

$$u = \frac{e^x}{x} - \frac{e^x}{x^2}$$

Therefore, our second solution is:

$$y_2 = ux^2 = \left(\frac{e^x}{x} - \frac{e^x}{x^2}\right)x^2 = xe^x - e^x = e^x(x-1)$$

Our general solution is:

$$y = c_1x^2 + c_2(e^x(x-1))$$

Comment: Varun Iyer, in the solutions it has the answer $y(x)=c_1x^2+c_2+e^x(x-1)$

Answer (score 1):

To answer how you get $u$ ty simply integrate $v$ w.r.t to x and then mutiply by $x^2$ to get $y$.

How did you get $v$?
As I get 
$$
v\mathrm{e}^{3\ln x} = vx^3 = \int \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ x}}{x}\mathrm{e}^{3\ln x}dx = \int x^2\mathrm{e}^x dx + c_1
$$
Which does not result in your answer for $v$?
The actual result is
$$
\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x^3}\mathrm{e}^x + \frac{c_1}{x^3}
$$
To evaluate the last integral I used 
$$
\int x^2 \mathrm{e}^x dx = \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha ^2}\int \mathrm{e}^{\alpha x} dx
$$ or you can use by parts :)

Comment: While this method is an alternative to solving the second order differential equation asked by OP, OP is specifically asking how to perform a certain method, not how to solve the differential equation.

Comment: I was solving $v$ as that was wrong. This is pretty much what your answer was doing sans wolfram. No?